# Checkbox mandatory if insert something in input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a function of woocommerce, like this example [image]

I need to put the checkbox obligatory,(mandatory) if you write something in the input, like a number for example.
But if you don't write nothing, should be not mandatory to check the checkbox, only if you insert text you have to check the checkbox,

Do you know how i can do?

I use this script but is no like i want, this only put checked if you write something.

```
    var ad = jQuery.noConflict();
ad( document ).ready(function() {

ad(function(){
  ad('#losung').keyup(function(){
    var adcb =  ad(this).parents('form:eq(0)').find('#num');
    if(this.value != '')
      adcb.attr('checked', 'checked');
    else
      adcb.removeAttr('checked');
  });
});
ad(function(){
  ad('#billing_email').keyup(function(){
    var adcb =  ad(this).parents('form:eq(0)').find('#subscription-box');
    if(this.value != '')
      adcb.attr('checked', 'checked');
    else
      adcb.removeAttr('checked');
  });
});

});
```

Thanks for you help!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `adcb.attr('checked', 'checked');` to `adcb.attr('required');` and `adcb.removeAttr('checked');` to `adcb.removeAttr('required');`